# Read data from .xlsx file in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to extract the data from a .xlsx file for that I am using POI-bin-3.11-beta2-2.jar,here my `FileInputStream` is created but the issue is in workbook. I think my xssf reference is not able to reach at the file location.

```
public class DemoExcel
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //File excel = new File("C:\\Users\\aditya.lodha\\Desktop\\test.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try{
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\aditya.lodha\\Desktop\\test.xlsx"));
            System.out.println("file found");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("file not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(fis.toString());
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        //HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        System.out.println(wb.toString());
        XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("tabledata");
        //HSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("XYZ");
        //System.out.println(sh.toString());
        int rowNum = sh.getLastRowNum()+1;
        System.out.println(rowNum);
        int colNum = sh.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        System.out.println(colNum);
        String data[][] = new String [rowNum][colNum];
        for(int i=0;i<rowNum;i++)
        {
            XSSFRow row = sh.getRow(i);
            for(int j=0;j<colNum;j++)
            {
                XSSFCell col = row.getCell(j);
                String value = celltoString(col);
                data[i][j] = value;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<rowNum;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<colNum;j++)
            System.out.println(data[i][j]);

        }
    }
    private static String celltoString(XSSFCell col)
    {
        int type;
        Object result;
        type = col.getCellType();
        switch (type)
        {
            case 0:
            result = col.getNumericCellValue();
            break;

            case 1:
            result = col.getStringCellValue();
            break;

            default:
            System.out.println(type);
            throw new RuntimeException("Runtime Exception");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

the error I am getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
>         at demo.DemoExcel.main(DemoExcel.java:31)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
>         ... 1 more

Comment: Something could be throwing : org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException :
Try adding it to class path, adding to pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to add the XML beans dependency to your class path.

Get the jar (http://poi.apache.org/download.html), go to Project, properties, Java build path, add external jar and select the .jar file, or simply put it on WEB-INF/libs, then the classloader will read it.

The name of the jar is something like `xmlbeans-(version).jar`

Comment: i followed your instruction but now its showing something different error

Comment: You can create another topic for this other error for organization, i think it is better than keep this one for several errors. I can help you there :D